# Vimeo embed padding resizes on play

Tags: html, css, video, embed, vimeo

Using a Vimeo embed on our homepage for a 21:9 aspect ratio video with a top padding of 42.41%. Full code below:

```
<div style="padding:42.41% 0 0 0 !important;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/849145174?h=0e12ee14c7&color=ec477f&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

It displays correctly on load, but when play is clicked it adjusts the padding to approx 43%, causing display issues with rounded corners. If you untick and re-tick either padding or display in Inspect it resets and plays fine.

Staging site at https://jonesmillbank.webflow.io with an example below of a 16:9 video (top padding of 56.25%) which doesn't adjust on play.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I love how just writing through an issue sheds a new thought on something. Turns out it was resetting to 42.5% so it twigged that it was rounded up/down to 0.5.

Adjusted the padding to 42.5% and adding margins of -10px to adjust the display correctly.

All sorted!